# Proper way to set two Rails applications on same server

Tags: configuration, ruby-on-rails-3.1, project

I have two (same) applications running on dev.example.com and beta.example.com with different databases. Everything is set to run with passenger using Apache as web server.

What I have done was to copy the code from one directory to the other (myapp_dev and myapp_beta) and everything seems working fine, until I have to migrate a table. I get an error that the data I want to migrate is already migrated. Probably trying to migrate on the same database. Maybe I have to re-configure the way to run the applications, but don't know how and what to do. Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the used database in config/database.yml

Comment: Actually the problem was with the wrong number of migrations in the schema_migrations table.

Anyway I was wondering if there is a good practice how to set the same project twice in the same server. Does only changing the database config finish the task?

Comment: you can use additional entries in the database.yml. you probably got production, test, development. we use an additional "staging" for our staging releases and "ci" for our continous integration builds.